# Flask SQLAlchemy - not updating, just adding a new record

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing a simple app for adding and updating information to sqlite3 database using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Now I have a big problem, because I cannot update the database, it just adds a new record every time I submit the form button.

Here is my code:

```
@main.route("/invoices", methods=["GET", "POST"], defaults={"invoice_id": None})
@main.route("/invoices/<int:invoice_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def invoices(invoice_id):
    invoice = None

    if invoice_id:
        invoice = Invoice.query.get_or_404(invoice_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        date = request.form["date"]
        name = request.form["name"]
        value = request.form["value"]
        currency = request.form["currency"]
        payment = request.form["payment"]
        category = request.form["category"]
        description = request.form["description"]

        if invoice:
            invoice.date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            invoice.name = name
            invoice.value = value
            invoice.currency = currency
            invoice.payment = payment
            invoice.category = category
            invoice.description = description

        else:
            invoice = Invoice(
                date=datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                name=name,
                value=value,
                currency=currency,
                payment=payment,
                category=category,
                description=description,
            )
            db.session.add(invoice)

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for("main.invoices", invoice_id=invoice.id))

    currencies = Currency.query.all()
    payments = Payment.query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()

    context = {
        "invoice_id": invoice_id,
        "currencies": currencies,
        "payments": payments,
        "categories": categories,
        "invoice": invoice,
    }

    return render_template("invoices.html", **context)
```

I don't know how to update the data, because it always adds a new record, now just commits the existing or changed fields. Maybe something wrong is with my if statements...

Please help me with this task...

Here is the models:

```
class Invoice(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))
    currency = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("currency.id"))
    payment = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("payment.id"))
    category = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("category.id"))


class Currency(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10))


class Payment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))


class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Comment: Can you share your model class as well?

Comment: @tedivm: I added the models above.

Answer (score -1):

This code may be help to you

```
@main.route("/invoices", methods=["GET", "POST"], defaults={"invoice_id": None})
@main.route("/invoices/<int:invoice_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def invoices(invoice_id):
    invoice = None

    if invoice_id is not None:
        invoice = Invoice.query.filter_by(id=invoice_id).first()

    if request.method == "POST":
        date = request.form["date"]
        name = request.form["name"]
        value = request.form["value"]
        currency = request.form["currency"]
        payment = request.form["payment"]
        category = request.form["category"]
        description = request.form["description"]

        if invoice is not None:
            invoice.date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            invoice.name = name
            invoice.value = value
            invoice.currency = currency
            invoice.payment = payment
            invoice.category = category
            invoice.description = description

        else:
            invoice = Invoice(
                date=datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
                name=name,
                value=value,
                currency=currency,
                payment=payment,
                category=category,
                description=description,
            )
            db.session.add(invoice)

        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for("main.invoices", invoice_id=invoice.id))

    currencies = Currency.query.all()
    payments = Payment.query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()

    context = {
        "invoice_id": invoice_id,
        "currencies": currencies,
        "payments": payments,
        "categories": categories,
        "invoice": invoice,
    }

    return render_template("invoices.html", **context)
```

Comment: Well, I doesn't help. In the models Invoice has attribute Invoice.id, so I guess it should be like this `invoice = Invoice.query.filter_by(id=invoice_id).first()`